# map three tables with primary keys and foreign keys Composite in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have to map these tables in hibernate and truth have tried in many ways and has not worked for me, having if I can help with this, I will not paste the code that I have because I suppose it's not right and I changed a lot.

### TABLE COUNTRY

idCountry  (PK)

countryName

### TABLE REGION

idRegion (PK)

idCountry (PK, FK)

RegionName

### TABLE PROVINCES

idProvinces (PK)

idRegion (PK,FK)

ProvincesName

Hopefully you can help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tables mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idCountry", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int countryId;

    @Column(name = "countryName", nullable = false)
    private String countryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "regionPk.country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<Region>(0);

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "REGION")
public class Region implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RegionPk regionPk;  //  RegionPk contains the composite PK

    @Column(name = "RegionName", nullable = false)
    private String regionName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "provincePk.region", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Province> provinces = new HashSet<Province>(0);

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()

}

@Embeddable
public class RegionPk implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idRegion", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int regionId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCountry", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PROVINCES")
public class Province implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProvincePk provincePk;  //  ProvincePk contains the composite PK

    @Column(name = "ProvinceName", nullable = false)
    private String provinceName;

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()

}

@Embeddable
public class ProvincePk implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idProvinces", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int provinceId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRegion", nullable = false)
    private Region region;

    // Generate Getters, Setters, hashCode() and equals()

}
```

Comment: Hello !, thanks for the reply, I followed your example and I do better but I am getting the following error:
A Foreign key refering com.test.mydb.entity.Region from com.test.mydb.entity.Province have the wrong number of column. Should be 2